# TreeModelFilter in GTK/Perl - Question about set_visible_func

Tags: perl, treeview, gtk, gtk2

I am trying to filter a liststore using the GTK2::TreeModelFilter. I can't seem to find an example online that uses perl and I am getting syntax errors. Can someone help me with the syntax below? The $unfiltered_store is a liststore.

```
$filtered_store = Gtk2::TreeModeFilter->new($unfiltered_store);
$filtered_store->set_visible_func(get_end_products, $unfiltered_store);
$combobox = Gtk2::ComboBoxEntry->new($filtered_store,1);
```

Then somewhere below:

```
 sub get_end_products {
      my ($a, $b) = @_;

      warn(Dumper(\$a));
      warn(Dumper(\$b));
      return true;     # Return all rows for now
 }
```

Ultimately what I want to do is look at column 14 of the listore ($unfiltered_store) and if it is a certain value, then it filtered into the $filtered_store.

Can someone help me with the syntax on this? I checked a bunch of sites, but they're in other languages and using different syntax (like 'new_filter' -- doesn't exist with Perl GTK).
This is the most elegant solution to a fix I need to make and I would prefer to learn how to use this rather than using a brute force method of pulling and saving the filtered data.

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the `get_end_products` sub routine. So try `$filtered_store->set_visible_func(\&get_end_products, $unfiltered_store)`

Comment: You mean like this?   $filtered_store->set_visible_func(\&get_end_products, $unfiltered_store);

Comment: FYi that even before passing by reference, the 'get_end_products' function is being called. My question has more to do with the store -- how do I access the store in the 'get_end_products' function? The two dumper statements print nothing, but the printing a warn statement like 'Hello World' inside the get_end_products function DOES work.

Comment: Hey! I just added the reference and ...it works! Program doesn't crash. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Great to hear! Note that generally, variables `$a` and `$b` are special variables used by the `sort` function. So it is not recommended to use those variable names.

Comment: Thanks again. So...can you help me with just the last part which is handling the parameters in the visible function. Is the liststore visible there? I just included $a and $b but wasn't even sure that would work (again, I couldn't find a working example). My last step is I need to check a certain column in the liststore and if it's set to a certain value, then I return true, otherwise, return false. I would be much obliged if you could help me with this last step. And this will be great for anyone else searching for a working Perl/GTK TreeModelFilter example. I found none online!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set_visible_func` method of the filtered store should get a sub reference as the first argument, but you are not passing a sub reference here:

```
$filtered_store->set_visible_func(get_end_products, $unfiltered_store);
```

This will instead *call* the sub routine `get_end_products` and then pass on its return value (which is not a sub reference). To fix it add the reference operator `\&` in front of the sub name:

```
$filtered_store->set_visible_func(\&get_end_products, $unfiltered_store);
```

Regarding your other question in the comments:
[According to the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreemodelfilter.html#method-gtktreemodelfilter--set-visible-func) the user data parameter is passed as the *third* parameter to `get_end_products`, so you should define it like this:

```
sub get_end_products {
      my ($model, $iter, $user_data) = @_;
      # Do something with $user_data
      return TRUE;
 }
```

If for some reason `$unfiltered_store` is not passed on to `get_end_products`, you can try pass it using an anonymous `sub` instead, like this:

```
$filtered_store->set_visible_func(
    sub { get_end_products( $unfiltered_store) });
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: If I use the anonymous sub, how do I access the iteration? Do I just pass it into the anonymous sub as a second parameter, etc?

Comment: Or just loop through the model, etc?

Comment: Yes you can try pass it like this `sub { get_end_products( $_[1], $unfiltered_store) }` . Now the first parameter will be the iteration, since `@_` should be equal to `($model, $iter, $user_data)`

Comment: I'm not able to check the value of the model's iteration. Performing  $val = $model->get_value($iter,$data) is returning a "Can't locate object method 'get_value'.." error. I need to see the value of the column before returning true/false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing more of your code. Maybe you could post some more of your code at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) for example? Or even better (?), if you upload all of your code, I could try run it.